# Thread dont flush data, error displaying the data in the screen

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, sockets

I'm creating a socket program to transfer data from one pc to another, but i have a problem when i send some binary data to process to the other side.
In this case i need one thread to listen the message socket while the data socket send the data.
So i discovered that the problem wasn't the socket, the problem happens if i try to just write the data to the screen (no socket this time).
So i tried to flush the data using fflush(stdout) and no luck.
The codes work in this way.

```
Initialize the 2 sockets.
Initialize 2 threads.
  One to get the data back through the data socket.
  The other send the data.    
And while sending all the data one while(true){sleep(1)} in the main function, because the data can take 1 second to be processed or one hour so i keep the program alive this way (Don't know if that is the better way).
```

I created a smaller version using just one thread to read and send to the screen and in the main just the while.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const int RCVBUFSIZE=2000;
char echoString[RCVBUFSIZE];

static void * _sendExec(void *instance);

int main(){
  pthread_t m_thread;
  int merror;
  merror=pthread_create(&m_thread, NULL, _sendExec, NULL);
  while(1){sleep(1);}
}
static void * _sendExec(void *instance){
  int size;
  for(;;){
    while((size=read(fileno(stdin), echoString, RCVBUFSIZE))>0) write(fileno(stdout), echoString, size);
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_exit(0);
  }
}
```

if you try cat file.tar.gz | ./a.out | tar -zvt you can see that not all the data is showed on the screen, if i put on the main, remove the sleep its ok, the problem is i need the data back and it can take time.
It's just like if i do an cat file.tar.gz | ssh root@server "tar -zvt".

Thanks people

Comment: sleep will block the whole process.  You could use a condition variable instead - look for examples of pthread_cond_timedwait.  I don't know why you lose some input but it may be related to that.  In your example you could just join the thread, though I guess that's a result of you forming a simplified example.  Replace it with a pthread_testcancel() and see if you get the same behaviour

Comment: Nice, so it's incorrect use a while to keep the thread alive, i imagined that's there's something wrong XD.

Comment: If you just want to make sure that your main doesn't complete before your thread has completed, then join the thread with pthread_join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume the code you provided is not the actual code you are using.. 
As wreckgar23 mentioned you should use pthread_join at the end of the main function if you want to wait for the thread to finish. You could remove the while(1){ sleep(1);}/pthread_exit(0), the pthread_join will make the main wait for the thread to finish.

Also using while(1)/for(;;) is not such a good idea.. you could at least use an int value set it to 0 and do all data processing until it changes it's value to 1. You could check for a certain "message" in the data you receive through the socket for a termination command and set the value of the int to 1.(and thus you can control the lifetime of your server through your(client) input, your entire server application can stop after you have finished processing the data..) If you do so, you should also take security implications into consideration..

You should also explicitly specify what kind of sockets you are using.. 
For example you might be loosing data if you use udp sockets and you have a small buffer..
Also, you can't print the data from your buffer and write to it at the same time. (it takes time to write the buffer to the screen.. while writing the data to the screen there might be new data arriving to the buffer and overwriting the old data before it gets a chance to print it)